# PHP app browser limit

Tags: php

I was found many class for detecting browser but I have problem with some of that, does anybody have easy source for this easy problem:

I want limit user who want work in one application only for Chrome and FF, I will make demo:

```
if($browser == 'Chrome' OR $browser == 'FF')
{
echo 'All ok';
}else
{
echo 'Not ok, I calling my internal redirection function and redirect user to applimit.php';
}
```

Comment: SO you've made a deliberate decision to prevent 50% of the world from being able to access your site: I thought the trend for only allowing hipsters to visit a website by telling everyone else that their browser wasn't cool enough for you died 10 years ago, and that cool developers now made cross-browser sites

Comment: @MarkBaker - I thought the trend is to make the website work with an actual browser that doesn't contain gremlins. And if it does, you warn the user that their experience will be shit due to their shit browser. No, cool developers don't do extra work. Cool developers are lazy. Hipster developers make cross-browser sites and "boast" with valid html/css links to w3.org. Bottom line - don't limit anything. Use client side technology to warn the user about bad user experience due to inadequate browser.

Comment: Hmmmmm... Must find browser that is fully compliant with all appropraie w3c RFCs, anybody have any idea f such a browser actually exists?

Comment: Oh, you added that into the fray.. and for a moment I thought you weren't a hipster. Oh well, have fun browsing with lynx then :)

Comment: @MarkBaker This is app with many jQuery, css3 (chrop, lightbox, response, etc. etc.) I try develop for other browser but many user have for example old IE and call me what is wrong, I agree that is not good policy redirect user to access my site but this is closed app not public web.

Comment: It's secret envy.... I envy anyone that can control the browsers used in a closed environment (and hence write specifically for that without worrying about versions or cross-browser compatibility); same as I envy library writers who have absolute control over the versions and config of PHP that they develop for

Comment: Given your reputation and experience, I believe you turn that envy into revenue. Same as Kogan did :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this, to know browser.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

[Reference php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)